# Remapping a single tag while deserializing

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, data-mapping

I've refactored code like this:

```
public string CamelCASE { get; set; }
```

to:

```
public string CamelCase {get; set; }
```

only do discover that the input XML contains the former casing (let's call it a shouting camel). I have no control over how the XML document is produced. Nor do I burn of desire to retract my changes.

I'd like to map the loud camel property to a softly speaking one.

I've tried *XmlElement* and *XmlMapping* but to no greater success. A googling gave me only hits on how to map stuff to **attributes**, along lines of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002651/net-serialization-best-practice-to-map-classes-to-elements-and-properties-to-a). However, I need only something like *<LoudCAMEL>* to be deserialized to a property *public string QuietCamel*.

Is there a smooth way to do so?

## Edit

After adding the attribute as follows:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;

public class Beep : SuperBeep
{
  private readonly BeepType _a;

  public Beep() { _a = BeepType.SomeSome; }
  public Beep(BeepType input) { _a = input; }
  ~Beep() { }
  public override void Dispose() { }

  public BeepType Aaa { get { return _a; } }

  [XmlElement("CamelCASE")]
  public bool CamelCase { get; set; }
}
```

I can see the red, wavy highlight telling me *Cannot access constructor 'XmlElement' here due its protection level*. When I compile, though, I get the IDE crying out loud that *'System.Xml.XmlElement' is not an attribute class*.

Frankly, I'm a bit confused by the suggestion to use attributes (this is targeting .NET 2.0), since I was under the impression that attributing wasn't available to .NET prior to version 3.5. Am I mistaken?

Comment: Re the edit: try changing it to `[XmlElementAttribute("CamelCASE")]` - semantically identical, but it might make the 2.0 compiler happy

Comment: Alternatively, double-check that you have `using System.Xml.Serialization;` at the top of the file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[XmlElement("CamelCASE")]
public string CamelCase { get; set; }
```

should be all you need, if you are keeping the shouty name in the xml. If you want to use the quieter name in *new* xml, but allow the *old* name to still work, it gets more complicated. You could use:

```
public string CamelCase { get; set; }

[XmlElement("CamelCASE"), Browsable(false)]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public string CamelCaseLegacy {
    get { return CamelCase; }
    set { CamelCase = value; }
}
[Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public bool ShouldSerializeCamelCaseLegacy() { return false; }
```

When serializing, the `CamelCase` property will serialize to `<CamelCase>`, and the `CamelCaseLegacy` element will be ignored due to the `ShouldSerialize*` method. However, when *deserializing*, the `CamelCaseLegacy` property will be used whenever `<CamelCASE>` is seen. We then map this value back to the `CamelCase` property.

Comment: +1 for completeness. Luckily, in my case, re-camelization won't be necessary.

Comment: Woah, I was a bit too quick to jump of joy. I just noticed that *XmlElement* caused a problem. Apparently, the project I'm working in is .NET 2.0. There are no attributes prior .NET 3.0 if I recall correctly. What to do then?!

Comment: @KonradViltersten that attribute has existed since 1.1; it should be there: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa335742(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Hmm... I'm not at work right now but as far I recall I got the compiler whining about the scope of the constructor of *XmlElement* being too narrow or something. Both my class and the property in it are public, though... Weird. Suggestions?

Comment: @Konrad my suggestion is: post the exact code that is problematic, and the exact error mesaage

Comment: That's because I underestimated how quick you're to read my stuff. Now you can see it.   :)

Answer (score 2):

You are referring to the wrong namespace.

Remove

```
using System.Xml;
```

and add

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;
```